# How to find the POD of the production Org if MyDomain has been enabled?

Tags: org, architecture, url, mydomain

Once you enable MyDomain, all URLs change from the POD-specific ones to be MyDomain-specific. Is there any easy way to find out the POD the Org is running on without contacting Salesforce?

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for Host URL following line will return full host url.

System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost()

If you are looking for instance on which your org is hosted then use following link

http://help.bluemangolearning.com/m/salesforce/l/40101-determining-the-salesforce-instance-when-using-my-domain

Comment: There seem to be an issue with resolving some of the MyDomains using the way described here. I had run a couple of Developer Edition Orgs against it, with no match. The issue is described here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2kdAAC  - another solution thus would be just to use nslookup with the MyDomain name - it seems to return the POD as part of the names returned.